Can two foliations of Minkowski spacetime share the same spacelike hyperplane?
I have a series of naive questions regarding the question in the title. Let $\mathcal{S}_1$ be a family of spacelike hyperplanes $\{\Sigma_1\}$ in $\mathbb{M}$. Let $\Sigma$ be one of these spacelike hyperplanes.

Can I always find (infinitely many?) families of spacelike hyperplanes which also contain $\Sigma$? Intuitively I want to say yes?
Let $\mathcal{U}$ and $\mathcal{V}$ be spacelike-separated regions of $\mathbb{M}$, both of which lie in the causal past of $\Sigma$, and such that there exists a $\tilde{\Sigma} \in \mathcal{S}_1$ for which $\mathcal{U}$ is in the causal future of $\tilde{\Sigma}$ while $\mathcal{V}$ is in the causal past of $\tilde{\Sigma}$. If 1. holds, can I always find at least one family $\mathcal{S}_2$ of spacelike hyperplanes which contains $\Sigma$ and which contains a spacelike hyperplane $\Sigma'$ for which $\mathcal{U}$ is now in the causal past of $\Sigma'$ while $\mathcal{V}$ is in the causal future of $\Sigma'$? Again, intuitively I want to say yes - since $\mathcal{U}$ and $\mathcal{V}$ are spacelike separated, there exists spacelike hyperplanes for which one is in the causal future while the other is in the causal past, and vice-versa.
Does the above still hold more generally in globally hyperbolic spacetimes?

Any proofs or references would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

What is your definition of "family of hyperplanes"? What is a "globally hyperbolic spacetime"?
